# How to install STM32CubeProgrammer in Linux

Tags: launcher, installed-programs

I installed STM32CubeProgrammer in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with the intention of [solving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055959/4645179) that I get when attempting to flash micro controllers in my STM32WB55 Nucleo Pack, but STM32CubeProgrammer doesn't launch upon installation.

Nothing happens when I click on the icon in the launcher and I didn't find any executable files for launching the program. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions in section 1.2.1 of the STM32CubeProgrammer [software description](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/76/3e/bd/0d/cf/4d/45/25/DM00403500/files/DM00403500.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00403500.pdf) worked for me.

I installed openjdk-8

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

I set selected java-8 as my default run time engine

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and installed the following packages

```
sudo apt purge openjfx
sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
sudo apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-jni libopenjfx-java
```

Then I installed the STM32CubeProgrammer as I had done earlier

```
sudo ./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.2.1.linux
```

The last page of the installation procedure mentioned the path to the program files. The following path now leads to the program files on my system

```
/usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/
```

The program can be launched using

```
sudo /usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/./STM32CubeProgrammer
```

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work under Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @DanielGlasser did you make it? If so, can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: @muyustan Unfortunately, not yet.  I did manage to get the programmer working with Windows 10, but it's not an ideal solution. I think that STMicro needs to update their software to use a closer to current version of the libraries.

Comment: @DanielGlasser ok, I made it, let me share how I did it in Ubuntu 20.04. ----------
I have followed the link below and installed java from Oracle.
Then it worked when I changed the default java version.
https://www.fosstechnix.com/install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @muyustan Thanks; I'll try that as soon as I can.

Comment: OK I just tried 1.40 the java 8 above in a virtual machine running ubuntu 20.04. It worked yesterday just after installation but now simply does nothing when invoked. Wish it gave a clue as to what it was unhappy with rather than just not doing anything. Even top does not catch anything. Getting frustrated will prob download 1.3

Comment: This is typical of big vendors. They literally expect you to reconfigure your entire computer around their IDE. Like I don't have anything else that uses Java on my computer. This is just the same mess as we were in with `cygwin1.dll` twenty years ago

Comment: Any advice on running without `sudo` though?

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions mentioned here did not work for me on Ubuntu20.04.

According to a user on the ST forum ([source](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BsRNNV/stm32cubeprogrammer-execute-fail-with-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-comstappmain)),
the JDK8 compatible version of openjfx is not available for Focal Fossa.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783369/install-openjdkopenjfx-8-on-ubuntu-20/62198111#62198111) describes a simple and effective solution.

To get around this issue you can install an OpenJDK version that includes JavaFX.

I installed [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) (making sure to select the full JDK)
Running

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/bellsoft-jdk8u275+1-linux-amd64-full.deb
```

This installs the JDK and updates alternatives.
(no need to run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`)

For me this was all I needed to do to get CubeProgrammer working

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working on Ubuntu 20.04 + openjdk 11.0.10

If you run STM32CubeProgrammer from cli you'll get a clue to the problem

```
./STM32CubeProgrammer
Error: Could not find or load main class com.st.app.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

So, annoyingly javafx is no longer packaged with java 9+

So the fix is to either find an older java or:

1. Download [javafx](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) and unpack to a folder
2. Update STM32CubeProgrammer script
   vi $(which STM32CubeProgrammer)

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/../lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH_TO_FX=/home/williao/tools/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX:$PATH_TO_FX/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web -jar $DIR/STM32CubeProgrammerLauncher
```

Don't forget to change PATH_TO_FX!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At some point all executables in the archive lose exec attribute - it has to be restored not only for the .linux file but for ./jre/bin/* also:

$ chmod -R 755 ./jre/bin

Answer (score -1):

I found this site while looking for how to fix the installer in Debian.  This worked for me.

```
$ sudo java -jar SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.8.0.exe
```